# scaleX(0) is taking up width

Tags: css, sass, hover, css-transforms

i'm trying to get this button to show only icons and reveal the buttontext only on hover, but i can't get it to work CSS only.

I already tried transitioning the width and max-width, which did not provide the expected result, the transition did not happen. it "jumped".

Heres the HTML

```
  <div class="button--text-container">
    Buttontext
  </div>
```

this is the according SCSS

```
&--text-container {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  font-size: $buttontext-size;
  line-height: $buttontext-size;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,.1);
}

&:hover {
  .button--text-container {
    margin-left: $buttontext-size;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

please check out the codepen i created:
https://codepen.io/hergi/pen/rNBxJGR

i expected the button to be round with the icon and revealing the buttontext with an animation. somehow the transform: scaleX(0) is not applying

Comment: You're looking for an accordion, or minimize-able effect.  These are a total hassle, because you can't tween between auto and anything else.  Typicallly, people use js to lock the width based off getBoundingClientRect(), then wait a frame, then set it to zero with transition.  In general, it's a pretty sloppy problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate the font-size:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.buttoncontainer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
}
.buttoncontainer .button {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: calc(20px * 1.5);
}
.buttoncontainer .button--icon-container {
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
}
.buttoncontainer .button--icon-container img {
  max-height: 20px;
  max-width: 20px;
}
.buttoncontainer .button--text-container {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
  transition: ease transform 0.2s, ease margin-left 0.2s,ease font-size 0.2s;
}
.buttoncontainer .button:hover .button--text-container {
  margin-left: 20px;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="buttoncontainer">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="button--icon-container">
        <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1157/1157044.svg" />
      </div>
      <div class="button--text-container">
        Buttontext
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```